# Failed to execute script.sh: unknown error

Tags: macos, bsd, dtrace

I wanted to use DTrace to see "what syscalls are made by my shell script".

I made a very simple shell script, `shell.sh`, and gave it execute privileges:

```shell
#!/bin/bash
grep 1 <<< 123
```

I `cd`'d into its directory, and ran this simple DTrace script:

```shell
sudo dtrace -n 'syscall:::entry
/pid == $target/
{
    @[probefunc] = count();
}' -c ./trace-me.sh
```

I get this error output:

```
dtrace: failed to execute ./trace-me.sh: unknown error
```

What happened here? I've run `csrutil enable --without dtrace`. The DTrace script runs fine if I remove the `-c` arg (and replace `$target` with a pid).

Is this just another Mac gotcha? I'm running macOS Sierra 10.12.5 Beta.

Comment: Have a look at this answer, it might solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36760408/499581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the [tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36760408/5257399) to which @l'L'l linked: I was able to work around this.

You'll need two shells.

In shell A (the shell we'll be inspecting):

```shell
# copy this shell's PID to clipboard (93827 for this example)
echo $$ | pbcopy
```

In shell B (the shell which will run DTrace), start tracing that PID:

```shell
sudo dtrace -n 'syscall:::entry
/progenyof($1) && pid != $1/
{
    @[probefunc] = count();
}' 93827
```

We use [`progenyof()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E38608/html/dt_progenyof_actsub.html) to ensure that we trace *child processes* of the shell. I've added `&& pid != $1` since for some reason `progenyof(x)` seems to include `x`.

Now back in shell A, run some code you'd like to inspect:

```shell
grep 1 <<< 123
```

Our DTrace program in shell B will successfully catch the child process launched in shell A.

There's a bit of noise to sift through. Maybe the shell launches a variety of children. Not sure how to be more selective.

---

It's educational to look at how dtruss implements `-f` ("follow children as they are forked")...

```shell
less "$(which dtruss)"
```

Relevant clauses are those using an `OPT_follow &&` filter (indicates that `-f` is enabled) or the `self->child` variable (indicates that this thread is a child of the process specified in `-p PID`).

It's also useful to know that [`ppid`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E38608/html/dt_builtin_dlang.html) is a built-in variable which gives you the parent PID.